# UIViewController inside CollectionViewCell memory problem

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am displaying UIViewController inside UICollectionViewCell. One cell per page. The problem is that when I swipe to go next page the memory keeps increasing and never comes back.

Here is the relevant code.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let newsVC: NewsTableVC = {
        return storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsListVC")
        }() as! NewsTableVC

    let cell = pagerCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PageCollectionViewCell

    //Wraping ViewController in CollectionView Cell
    return wrapAndGetCell(viewColtroller: newsVC, cell: cell)

}

func wrapAndGetCell(viewColtroller: UIViewController, cell: PageCollectionViewCell) -> PageCollectionViewCell{
    //setting tag to remove view when it's being reused
    viewColtroller.view.tag = PageCollectionViewCell.SUBVIEW_TAG
    addChild(viewColtroller)
    viewColtroller.view.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
    cell.contentView.addSubview(viewColtroller.view)
    viewColtroller.didMove(toParent: self)
    return cell
}
```

And here is collectionViewCell class

```
class PageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    static let SUBVIEW_TAG: Int = 1000

    override func prepareForReuse(){
        super.prepareForReuse()
        let subViews = self.contentView.subviews
        for subView in subViews{
            if subView.tag == PageCollectionViewCell.SUBVIEW_TAG{
                subView.removeFromSuperview()
                print("subView removed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the problem is with adding SubViews in each cell, but I also remove subViews in `perpareForReuse()` method.

Please help me in identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new `NewsTableVC` every time a cell is dequeued. All you need to do is just reuse the same view controllers instead of creating a new one each time you get a cell.

Create an array of type `[NewsTableVC]` and then do like this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let newsVC = self.newsVCArray[indexPath.item]

    let cell = pagerCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PageCollectionViewCell

    //Wraping ViewController in CollectionView Cell
    return wrapAndGetCell(viewColtroller: newsVC, cell: cell)

}
```

This should fix your memory issues, but creating adding a viewController's view as a collectionViewCell subview seems like a strange thing to do. Unless you have a very good reason for doing this, I'd recommend just using the `PageCollectionViewCell`'s and forget about the `NewsTableVC` entirely.

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but it's hard to imagine a scenario where it makes sense to use a collectionViewCell this way.

Comment: Thanks @LulzCow it solved my issue.
Basically I need to display different types of UIViewControllers in CollectionView. I can't make each UIVC as CollectionViewCell because these are being reused somewhere else that's why I'm doing it this way (wrapping in CollectionViewCell). If you think know some other better approach than please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem

```
addChild(viewColtroller)  //1
viewColtroller.view.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
cell.contentView.addSubview(viewColtroller.view)
viewColtroller.didMove(toParent: self)
```

(1*) *self* (UIViewController) strongly retains the "child" ViewController

When you prepareForReuse the cell, you are only removing the "childViewController" view from the heriarchy, but the "childViewController" itself is still being retained by the UIViewController (parent).

When you dequeue a new cell, you repeat the process, creating a new child and adding it to the parent WITHOUT removing the previous one

```
viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
```

, so the childs are not released. This is increasing the memory with each cell dequeued (actually each new childViewController added to the parent).

A good way to confirm this, is placing a breakpoint on the "child" viewcontroller deinit method.

```
  deinit {
// Breakpoint here
print("DEINIT")
}
```

NOTE: the print here is required, an empty method will not catch the breakpoint.

Also, to debug it, you can print the childViewControllers, right before adding a new child

```
print(self.childViewControllers)
```

So, in resume, the problem here is that the cildViewControllers are being retained by the "parent", and you are adding new ones on each dequeue.

Hope this help, and sorry for the length of the response.